# JBoss 7 - Loading jars programatically from a module classloader

Tags: classloader, jboss7.x, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a WAR that I have deployed to JBoss 7 that dynamicially loads jar resources using its context class loader.

```
final ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
propertiesUrls = cl.getResources(TRANSLATION_PROPERTIES);
```

However the context classloader only looks for resources in the WEB-INF/lib folder

ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment..war:main" from Service Module Loader

How do I get hold of a classloader for a specific module in jboss that I have the resources in. I have the jars that i need to load in a custom module in JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/custom/...

Comment: Do you have a dependency in your WAR on the module you created?

Comment: Yes i have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml that specifies the module as a dependency bundled in the WEB-INF folder of the war. JBoss container itself seems to figure the classes in the module. Its just that its loaded from a different classloader (modules are loaded in its own classloader in JBoss 7) and I need to get hold of the classloader. The current thread context classloader always is the default war loader but how do i get to the module classloader.

Comment: Nevermind I had to use the current classloader instead of the Thread context classloader. this.getClass().getClassLoader() instead of Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()

Comment: @abhishekhp you could add that as an answer and mark this as answered

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the current classloader instead of the Thread context classloader. i.e. this.getClass().getClassLoader() instead of Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()